# InDesign: How to change the position of a textbox to match the height of another textbox beside it?

Tags: adobe-indesign

[image]

I have a textbox containing the main content [P]
A textbox [C1] is to always align with the upper border of [P]. I have done this by anchoring it to the start of [P].

Another textbox containing other content is [C2]. It is to always stay above [P] but with a certain gap shown by the blue arrows.
[C21] is the child of [C2] and will change its position when content within [C2] changes. I have anchored it to [C2]

Next, there is a dividing vertical line which should change its height automatically when content changes in either [P] or [C2].

Now all I've done is anchored [C1] to start of [P], auto-sized [P] with height changing from mid-bottom.
Similarly, I've anchored [C21] to start of [C2], auto-sized [C2] with height changing from mid-bottom, and also Anchored [C2] to [P].

But when I change the height of [P] both [C2] & [C21] disappear instead of getting pushed to the top.

Also, I've no idea of how to make the vertical line change its height according to heights of both [P] & [C2]

Can this be done in InDesign?

> [P]=Parent Textbox
>  [C1]=1st Child
>  [C2]=2nd child
>  [C21]=
>   1st Child of [C2]
>  [C22]= 2nd child of [C2]

Comment: Could you insert in the question a graphic example with all the options: what do you have and what do you want, please?

Comment: I wonder why did you anchored C2 to P? I have the feeling that you are misusing the anchors objects for relationships between paragraphs. About the paragraph left line is something simple to do in the latest Indesign versions, it would be useful to indicate the version you use.

Comment: Seems to me.. using **one** text frame and then utilizing the paragraph **space before/after** would be a better option. That may merely be my preference though. I try and use as *few* text frames as possible, instead opting for text styling which includes any spacing necessary, including text frame offsets when needed.

Comment: Why don't you use a table with only a visible centwred border? Everything including your vertical line (border)will adjust on content change if set up correctly. 2 rows, 2 columns. And that's all

Comment: I'm an idiot!! Was complicating things. That's why people say "Keep It Simple! Silly". Thanks solved my problem. Should I keep this question up or should I delete it? I don't think anyone else will benefit from this question.

Comment: I don't know what answer you are referring to @YourPalNurav but I secretly hope it was Scott's. That was definitely the best advice. About the left, you can achieve it using paragraph border feature